# How I can get the value of check radio button in update page

Tags: python, html, django

How I can get the value of check radio button in update page, it save it DB but in update page it did not show the selected radio button.

in models

```
class UserListGroup(models.Model):
user_role = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="USER")
    def __int__(self):
        return self.ulg_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'userlist_group'
```

in add html

```
<tr>
   <td class="mtrr"><b>User Role*</b></td>
   <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="user_role" value="admin" checked>Admin</label></td>
   <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="user_role" value="super">Super User</label></td>
   <td class="mtt"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="user_role" value="user">User</label></td>
</tr>
```

in update add html

```
 <tr>
     <td class="mtrr"><b>User Role*</b></td>
     <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input {% if data.ul_role == True %} checked {% endif %} type="radio" name="user_role">Admin</label></td>
     <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input {% if data.ul_role == True %} checked {% endif %} type="radio" name="user_role">Super User</label></td>
     <td class="mtt"><label class="radio-inline"><input  {% if data.ul_role == True %} checked {% endif %}  type="radio" name="user_role">User</label></td>
</tr>
```

in view

```
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.POST
user_role = form.get('user_role')
employee_master = UserListGroup.objects.create(user_role=user_role,
                                                         )//other code
```

Comment: are you using django or something? might be good to add the relevant tag

Answer (score 0):

Your information is a bit incomplete as you left out the update view

You can solve your problem as follows

**Add CHOICE attribute to your user_role field**

In model:

```
class UserListGroup(models.Model):
    ROLE = (('user', 'USER'), ('admin', 'ADMIN'), ('super', 'SUPER USER')) 
    user_role = models.Charfield(max_length=25, choices=ROLES, default=user)
```

using choices will cause a  html widget to be used, to use a radio button, create a Django form and update it as below

```
from Django forms import ModelForm, RadioSelect
from .models import UserListGroup

class UserListGroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserListGroup
        field = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'user_role': RadioSelect()
        }
```

Your add.html and update.html would look similar to

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

For such simple crude operation, you are better off using the Django generic view

On a final note, the approach you use in your update.html in checking for the current user role is wrong, as the condition is same in all three cases. It should be compared with their possible database values as follows

```
<tr>
     <td class="mtrr"><b>User Role*</b></td>
     <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input {% if data.ul_role == 'admin' %} checked {% endif %} type="radio" name="user_role">Admin</label></td>
     <td class="mtrr"><label class="radio-inline"><input {% if data.ul_role == 'super' %} checked {% endif %} type="radio" name="user_role">Super User</label></td>
     <td class="mtt"><label class="radio-inline"><input  {% if data.ul_role == 'user' %} checked {% endif %}  type="radio" name="user_role">User</label></td>
</tr>
```